# Insert query into multiple databases

Tags: php

I have a ticket system I set up for multiple websites. Each website has its own database and the tables in each database are the same on all website with a few minor changes on each site.

I'm creating a CMS to manage all the sites from one website.

I can query my databases and have variable setup like this to call each database.

- `$database_1 = 'cats';`
- `$database_2 = 'dogs';`

Then call the database like this in a query:

```
SELECT `whatever` FROM {$database_1}.`support_ticket`..etc
```

My question is how can I insert data into the database tables?

This works for me:

```
$addticket = DB::getInstance()->insert('cats.`st_messages`', array( etc..
```

But I want it to work like this:

```
$addticket = DB::getInstance()->insert('{$database_1}.`st_messages`', array( etc..
```

Not sure why that won't work..?

So to reiterate:

- `$database_1 = 'cats';`
- This works: `'cats.st_messages'`
- This is not working, but want it to: `'{$database_1}.st_messages'`

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong by using the variable in the insert query I would appreciate it.

Comment: Connect to each database separately and then refer to that connection ID when running your query

Comment: @JohnConde I believe that's what I'm trying to do. I have a DB called cats and on called dogs etc.. Each is connected separately.
I refer to the connection by `$database_1 = 'cats';` ,but when running my insert line `'{$database_1}.st_messages'` it's not reading it as `'cats.st_messages'`......What I'm asking is what is wrong with this: `'{$database_1}.st_messages'` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use double quotes when building your strings otherwise they will not be interpolated.